# How to return the value of a counter in Python when comparing non-identical elements?

Tags: python, list, compare, counter

I have the following list:

```
x = [['A', 'A', 'A', 'A'], ['C', 'T', 'C', 'C'], ['G', 'T', 'C', 'C'], ['T', 'T', 'C', 'C'], ['A', 'T', 'C']]
```

I need to compare each element in sub_list to the other and note number of changes

```
x[0] --> # No change 
x[1] --> # 1 change (Only one conversion from C to T (T to C conversion = C to T conversion))
x[2] --> # 3 changes(G to T, T to C, G to C (T to C conversion = C to T conversion))
```

....
So, final count for Changes should be [0,1,3,2,3]

Comment: not very clear. could you provide an exemple of exactly what you expect for your `x`input?

Comment: I have mentioned in the question what the x input is. x[0] refers to the first subllist in x, which is ['A', 'A', 'A', 'A']

Comment: Well my comment is actually not verry clear too. what I wanted was the expected output, given the `x input`. anyway, I tried an answer...

Comment: okay I am amending the question

Comment: **part 1**: the text says to keep count of non ATGC elements but the exemple following counts the ATGC element. which is the correct behaviour? **part 2**: C -> T and T -> C are considered as the same transition? your explanations are not coherent, in x[2] I see only two changes, not 3. please take care of your exemples if you want to get some help

Comment: @Tryph I have simplified the question. Thanks for pointing out the errors

Comment: I still do not understand something: in x[2] you consider G -> C conversion. Do you mean that conversion are done also between the first and the last element of the sub list?

Comment: Every element in the sublist has to be compared with every other element in the sublist. But every comparison is unique. So, if I have ' AGCC* '. (Here C = C*. I have denoted it for easy understanding of position). A to G is 1 conversion, G to C is another, A to C is another. G to C* is same as G to C and A to C* is same as A to C.

Comment: I think I finally got it. check my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand well...

```
from collections import Counter
from itertools import combinations

x = [['A', 'A', 'A', 'A'],
     ['C', 'T', 'C', 'C'],
     ['G', 'T', 'C', 'C'],
     ['T', 'T', 'C', 'C'],
     ['A', 'T', 'C', 'Z']]


def divide_and_square(number, divisor):
    return (1. * number / divisor) ** 2


# part1
counters = [Counter(sub_list) for sub_list in x]
atgc_counts = [sum(val for key, val in counter.items()
                   if key.upper() in "ATGC")
               for counter in counters]
print(atgc_counts)

# part 2
conversions = []
for sl in x:
    sub_list = [base for base in sl if base.upper() in "ATGC"]
    conversions.append(len(list(combinations(set(sub_list), 2))))
print(conversions)

# bonus
squared_factor_sums = []
for counter in counters:
    total = sum(counter.itervalues())
    squared_factor_sums.append(sum([divide_and_square(val, total)
                                    for val in counter.values()]))
print(squared_factor_sums)
```

prints:

```
[4, 4, 4, 4, 3]
[0, 1, 3, 1, 3]
[1.0, 0.625, 0.375, 0.5, 0.25]
```

- first the character other that ATGC are removed.
- then the duplications are avoided by casting the sub_list into a set
- [itertools.combinations](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html?highlight=itertools.combinations#itertools.combinations) is used to get all the unique combinations of the elements in the set
- combinations are finally counted

Comment: Thanks a lot. I had a question regarding your previous post. counters = [Counter(sub_list) for sub_list in x]. ... x[1] output is --> Counter({'C': 3, 'T': 1}). Now, I want to divide 3 and 1 by the length of the sublist (here, it is 4), square and then add them. So, (3/4)^2 + (1/4)^2. Any ideas? I want to do this for each element in the list.

Comment: @Biotechgeek This should normally be a new question... but since I am not too rigid, look at the answer update.